# ASCX result to call javascript found in ASPX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a user control (MyListSelect.ascx) that just has a list of radio buttons...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<select>
    <option disabled selected>Select Options</option>
    <option>
        option 1
    </option>
    <option>
        option 2
    </option>
</select>
```

My ASPX page has:

```
<%@Register Src="~/MylistSelect.ascx" 
            TagName="listSelect" 
            TagPrefix="ListControl" %> 

<ListControl:listSelect runat="server" />
```

This displays in my ASPX a dropdown menu (woo hoo);

I want to be able to (form the ASPX) call a javascript function based on the selected index change event for the dropdown since the menu item selected will have different functionality in different pages. I dont' want to define all possible functionality in the ASCX.

Any suggestions? lso, Why does `<ListControl:listSelect runat="server" />` have to runat server? is there a way around this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your select to this:

```
<select onchange="yourJSFunction();">
```

When you use the control inside the page you'll also provide the `yourJSFunction`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yourJSFunction() {
        alert("yourJSFunction 1");
    }
</script>

<ListControl:listSelect runat="server" />
```

In another page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yourJSFunction() {
        alert("yourJSFunction 2");
    }
</script>

<ListControl:listSelect runat="server" />
```

Comment: I disagree with this approach entirely. What happens when you put this control on a page that doesn't have the function defined? Javascript error.

Answer (score 4):

It must be `runat=server` because user controls are special controls processed by the .net engine on server side. An ASP.NET User Control doesn't make any sense on client side, it needs a "translation" before be sent to client.

In order to respond to selected index change event first you'll need to assign an id or a css class to the `select` so you can identify it more accurately trough a jQuery selector (assuming you want to use jQuery since you added it to question tags).

Something like this should do the trick

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option disabled selected>Select Options</option>
    <option>
        option 1
    </option>
    <option>
        option 2
    </option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    $('#mySelect').change(function(){
         // your logic when index changed here
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer is the way to go. The page can know about the contents of the control, because it's instantiating the control, but avoid putting any code in the control that makes assumptions about the page it's instantiated on. That's a recipe for future headaches.